# How to compare number string in filter operator?

Tags: java, jsonpath, jayway

```
data: [
    {
        "name": "mark",
        "age": "20"
    },
    {
        "name": "john",
        "age": "10"
    }
]
```

in this case, how to get age greater than 10?

sample code:

```
JsonPath.read(json, "$.data[?(@.age > 10)]");
```

Comment: you can marshall it to a java object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using Jayway's JsonPath library.
First, the JSON you showed is not good for processing, the wrapping `{ }` are missing.
Second, Jayway's comparison operator works if you test against the number as a string (It's a bit weird but the library does the required casting internally that way).

So, with this JSON:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"mark",
         "age":"20"
      },
      {
         "name":"john",
         "age":"10"
      }
   ]
}
```

And this filter:

```
$.data[?(@.age > '10')]
```

You get the expected result `[{"name" : "mark", "age" : "20"}]`. You can test it [online here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

**Update**

As pointed out by [Parveen Verma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2116590/parveen-verma), the suggested filter will not work if the range filter requires an implicit type conversion.
Jayway seems to only support implicit conversions when using the equality operators, e.g. `$.data[?(@.age == 10)]` (this works despite the type differences).

There is an unmerged [pull request](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/pull/297) that adds this behavior; since the code is somewhat behind the current version it may require some work to integrate it but if you really need this functionality it can be done.

Comment: Strings don't behave like integer. Below will not work :
$.data[?(@.age > '9')]

Comment: it work only if comparison done with similar characters. It will not work for number comparison.
Have you tried  - $.data[?(@.age > '9')]
With linked website.

Comment: @ParveenVerma Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.